# Get a notification when an AWS EC2 instance has been running for a specific amount of time?

Tags: amazon-ec2

We have some AWS machines that get automatically launched, used for tests, and dismantled (by a system we made using the AWS API).

It can happen that something goes wrong and that the machine doesn't get dismantled, and just sits there, running 24/7, until someone notices it.

We're thinking about setting up some kind of system to notify us when this happens.

**Is there any way to set up a notification system when an instance matching specific criteria has been running for a set amount of time?**

It would be best if it was something already integrated in EC2/AWS that doesn't involve third party tools, but I'm open to any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing pre-made in AWS that does this, however it's trivial to write a small script that you can run via cron (or Lambda even) that gathers information on your instances and emails you if certain conditions are met.

Comment: I did this in the end, yeah. It probably wasn't the simplest, but it worked for our purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Is it [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491919/set-up-an-aws-alert-to-send-a-message-if-one-of-a-set-of-instances-is-running-lo/42493163)?

My answer: 
I believe this task is for Lambda:

- use `aws ec2 describe-instances` equivalent using lambda to get Launchtime
- lambda function crawl across those metrics. If any instance runs longer than needed then the same lambda function can stop it, send message or whatever you want.
- profit! :)